# No response to account deletion requests?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I have requested for my account to be deleted about 5 times now (not an exaggeration) through the deletion request form https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion with the corresponding "please delete me" on my user description.

It has been almost a month and I haven't received any confirmation or email response. I've submitted a new request each week and I just sent one again yesterday.

> There should at least be an automated response email upon form
>   submission that the request is pending approval and a follow-up email
>   of whether it was accepted or denied.

As of now, it seems as though you can delete an account at any given moment, which is how it should be. However if there are any reasons an account can not be deleted, maybe it would be best to put them on the deletion request form page.

It's pretty standard on just about every website, I don't see why something so basic is not incorporated here. As to my problem, can an admin shed some light as to why my account hasn't been deleted?

Comment: Which accounts did you want removed? Just Stack Overflow and Meta? I see your Server Fault account doesn't have a "please delete me" in the profile.

Comment: all of them, I will put that on all my profiles

Comment: You may not leave, SE is a sectaric organization or something

Answer (score 2):

Hrm. That forms effectively emails us and I'm not seeing any emails from you or that mention your account, not even in the spam folder. (We do have filters set up to prevent these support requests from landing in Spam, but I checked anyway just in case.)

Did you get any errors when using the form?

I have zero idea what went wrong here. Either way, I'll be removing your accounts shortly. Sorry about that.

Comment: I share a network with 5 other roommates, so I use hotspotshield so people don't know what dirty things I'm searching for. Perhaps that's in the filters? Just thought of that.

Comment: Possibly related: I submitted a request through that form pretty recently [which Rebecca didn't see when she looked for it](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1167497#116749). (Though I can't be sure that it wasn't just a searching matter.)