# Unable to delete account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

Several days ago I decided to remove my account on the Information Security site as I haven't used it nearly as much as my other sites and I have no intention of using it in the future. I've submitted the form on the contact page multiple times and haven't received any sort of email confirmation or response, and I noticed [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155379/no-response-to-account-deletion-requests) which had a similar problem so I was hoping one of the admins could delete my account as well.

**Just to be clear:** I only want my Information Security account deleted, not any of my other ones.

Comment: You did not follow the steps. For one, the About Me section of the account to be deleted must be "please delete me", or something like this. In [your case](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/8586/gustevesun), it's empty. Without it, any user can ask to delete any other user's account. The team most likely get tons of such false requests from frustrated users trying to delete accounts of those who upset them, so they just silently ignore requests where the target account failed to change the "About Me" section.

Comment: @ShadowWizard while true, the Help Center does not state that part of the process.  The help center only says "After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions."

Comment: @psubsee2003 true, for some reason I assumed the Help Center describes the actual steps to delete, but turns out it just asks the user to just send the form. So guess OP here only need to wait...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it used to be there.  It was definitely in the [faq for deleting accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account), but was [removed about a month ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/7979/revisions).  Apparently that step isn't required, if the edit comment from that deleted user can be trusted.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks, totally missed that it's not required anymore. This is really weird, as now people can send fake delete requests...

Comment: @ShadowWizard it was news to me as well until about 4 minutes ago when I was trying to figure out where that requirement disappeared.

Comment: I was never aware that that was part of the process since it doesn't say it in the help center, nonetheless I've changed my About Me

Answer (score 2):

The question you linked said it was almost a month after the initial request, you said your decision to delete your account was only made "several days ago", which I will interpret as less than a week, so I doubt this is the same problem.

The deletion process is a manual process, so someone needs to read your email and act upon it.  There is a large volume of incoming email for the community team so it takes a few days to get to messages.  And you had the misfortune of deciding to delete your account on a holiday weekend in the United States (Thursday is a national holiday, and Friday is a common holiday and/or vacation day for many people, so a 4-day weekend is extremely common).  This means the most likely explanation is no one is actually working to be able to respond or act upon the request.

Long story short, patience, you've submitted multiple requests now, but chances are no one has read the first one.  So just be patient and stop submitting delete requests until you are sure the first one was missed, which means give it much more time than a week.

Comment: My apologies, but I assumed the message saying I should get an email response "shortly" was an automated response letting me know that my request was received

Comment: @Oztaco probably was an automated response, but the actual deletion still requires some manual intervention. I don't know the exact process anymore, but you will likely get an email from one of the community managers explaining how to proceed.  There will likely be some action required on your part to prove you own the account and to clarify exactly which account you want to be deleted.  The extra effort is necessary because once done, your account cannot be undeleted so they have to be careful to ensure they know who you are and exactly what you want.